# How to put \ast in bookmark?

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, warnings

I need

```
\section{\texorpdfstring{$V^\ast$}{V\textasciicircum\ast}}
```

but `\ast` yields a warning.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You just want an approximate representation, in the bookmark, so `\texorpdfstring{$V^{*}$}{V*}$` should do. (Note that `\ast` is just an alternate name for `*` in math mode.)

Answer (score 2):

With option `unicode`/`pdfencoding=auto` and `psdextra`, many math operators including `\ast` are available in bookmarks. (Option `unicode` is not related to the input encoding, but to the encoding of the bookmarks. Option `pdfencoding=auto` uses Unicode if needed, otherwise the 8-bit PdfDocEncoding is used.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto,psdextra]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}% more features, faster updated bookmarks

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{\texorpdfstring{$V^\ast$}{V\textasciicircum\ast}}
\section{\texorpdfstring{$V^\ast$}{V\textasciicircum*}}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result AR9/Linux]

**Remarks:**

Unicode does not provide a superscript asterisk.

- The notation using `^` might be clear for TeX users and confuse others.
- The result looks nicer without `^` in this case, see egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170633/16967).
- Avoid math in section titles, if possible. There are other problems beside bookmarks. For example, section titles are usually set with a bold font. It looks poor, if the math is not bold. If math is set in bold, it might change its meaning, if variables become vectors.

Answer (score 2):

The text in the bookmarks is not typeset: font changes are not possible and math formatting is impossible. So the best you can get is an approximate representation of the title. In this case I suggest

```
\section{\texorpdfstring{$V^{\ast}$}{V*}}
```

Minimal example with picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{\texorpdfstring{$V^{\ast}$}{V*}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You see that this is even more accurate than writing `V\textasciicircum\ast` because the asterisk in text fonts is usually in a high position.